# Two PPS inputs for accurate time

Tags: raspbian, gps

I have read that it is no problem to use the GPS PPS pin to give the Raspberry Pi accurate time. My problem is that I want to use the 1 HZ PPS signal from the RTC (DS3231). If the GPS does have a fix, and then gets a fix it should synchronise the RTC module with the GPS PPS. Can I use two PPS signals to set the time?
Anybody an idea how to do this?

Comment: You will have to make some kind of switch? Or software to decide where to get the time from I suppose.

Comment: Currently this question is a overly broad, and should be closed.  What have you tried? Are you using an existing model and get stuck at a particular part?

Comment: It seems to me the OP wants to use/have a RTC and he wants to synchronise/update it whenever he has valid time data from the GPS system.  I think a read of the man-pages for ntp.conf may be relevant here.

Comment: Oh, and a quick search turned [this](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Sandbox/HowtoPpsOnRaspberryPi) article up - it seems related.